# Kbuntu 16.04 doesn't boot

Tags: boot, 16.04

I downloaded the ISO file for Kbuntu 16.04 (32 BIT) and burned it to a DVD. I then rebooted the computer and installed KBUNTU into the "Entire Disk", since I had no use for Win XP anymore.

After completing the installation and just before the message that tells me to remove the installation disk and reboot, there were several error message indicating that there was insufficient room on a device. I could only assume that these were referring to the DVD, which couldn't be written to.

I followed through with the reboot and words "KBUNTU" appeared then disappeared followed by a blank screen. I left the PC running for over an hour and nothing else appeared. I rebooted with the same effect.

Comment: Boot from the Ubuntu DVD again, select "Try without installing", open a terminal window (CTRL+ALT+T) and type the command `sudo parted -l`. It will ask you for a password, but simply leave that blank and hit ENTER. Then copy that output and [edit] your question to add it, please. This will show us information about your disk and the partitions on it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it kept asking me for a login. I used the login that I had chosen for the first install as well as nothing and got nowhere. I finally gave up. It's not worth the effort. I spent over 4 hours on this today and got no where. Thanks for the attempt!

Comment: If you use `sudo` (which you have to do there), it will ask you for the current account's password. On the live DVD, the current user (who is named `ubuntu` btw.) has an empty password, so all you need to do is enter *nothing* and immediately press ENTER when you're asked for the admin password.

Comment: I tried XUBUNTU and it installed and booted fine. I suspect that KUBUNTU isn't compatible with my older system.